# How to properly set session.gc_lifetime?

Tags: php

First of all, I am asking this because I checked other questions and couldn't find an answer about this, so I maybe did this correctly but there's no way to find out (at least I think) without waiting 7 days, so, I created a .htaccess file with this:

```php
RewriteEngine on
session.gc_maxlifetime = 604800‬
```

Is this all I had to do? Did I even do it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close. You do need to change your format to match that of the `.htaccess` syntax.

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 604800‬
```

To allow settings changes via `.htaccess` you may also have to modify your site configuration file to allow overrides:

```
AllowOverride Options
```

Check this documentation page for even more information: https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php